# How to read a csv file for variables and dictionaries from different columns?

Tags: python, csv

So I have a CSV file with 2 columns one of the columns being the dictionary key (All the values for the keys are 1) and a column for time which is only in one cell as its the final time. I have found a code that works but it seems a bit excessive and was wondering if anyone knows of any way of shortening it down?

```
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    mydict = {columns[0]:1 for columns in reader}
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    time = [columns[1] for columns in reader][0]
```

I've tried writing it as below but that didn't work can someone explain why:

```
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    mydict = {columns[0]:1 for columns in reader}
    time = [columns[1] for columns in reader][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.reader` returns an iterable, so once it has been exhausted through iteration it will not yield any more items unless you perform a file seek to reset the file pointer.

For your purpose you should simply use `zip` to pair the two columns and unpack them into two lists. Since you only need the first time, you can further unpack the second list to extract the first item. And you can then the build the dict from the list of keys using the `dict.fromkeys` method:

```
with open('coors.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    keys, (time, *_) = zip(*reader)
    mydict = dict.fromkeys(keys, 1)
```